# Limited user requires admin rights for plug and play printer?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, printer

I have a small fleet of laptops that aren't part of a domain running Windows XP Pro SP3 as limited users.

They are used for printing different shipping documents.

I have a script that runs when they start up that uses devcon and prntmngr to detect and install/configure the currently connected usb printers.

This lets us deploy the laptops to any printing station with a USB printer and have the printer 'just work' for the end user employee.

I've taken the original clone image and have added functionality to it.  Since then I've discovered a bit of an issue with using HP LaserJet P1606dn printers.  They have started asking for admin rights on setup.  This is with and without the script running.  Previously they would automatically install because I had installed WHQL plug and play drivers for them.

I thought it might have to do with the [HP Smart Install Utility](https://superuser.com/questions/340621/why-would-all-usb-printers-of-a-specific-model-show-as-offline-after-every-reboo) but it happens when that is disabled.

I don't have a good point to roll back to before this started happening because this was an issue on the image I took initially to start this upgrade.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try executing your script as an administrator? And in your script launch the installation as an administrator as well?